# Problem with sf package in R: How can I solve it?

Tags: r, error-handling, r-sf

Got the following error message after installing "sf" package in R.
It seems to have something to do with a prior installation of "tmap".
I get the same error message for library(tmap).

R version 4.0.2
install.packages('sf')

> library(sf)
> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’:
> .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'units' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
> Aufruf: udunits_init(file.path(.get_ud_xml_dir(), "udunits2.xml"))
> Fehler: Error in function udunits_init: Can't open installed, default, unit database

is there anything I can do? I am completely lost.

Comment: Looks like your error is on the package `udunits2` or `units`, since your error message says 'Error in function udunits_init'. Do those packages load? https://github.com/r-quantities/units/issues/184

Answer (score 0):

After reading several threads, the solution that worked for me was to install and manually load the package `udunits2`.